# How change the css style applied to a jsf div with a type of message?

Tags: css, jsf, message

for a crud application I would like to create a div where I want to display a message and change the color of the div with the type of message.

At the moment I have this code in my jsf file:

```
<ui:define name="msg">
    <h:messages globalOnly="true" errorClass="err" warnClass="warn" infoClass="info"></h:messages>
    <h:messages globalOnly="false" errorClass="err" warnClass="warn" infoClass="info"></h:messages>
```

My div is defined in a template xhtml:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger" id="msg2">
            <ui:insert name="msg"></ui:insert>
```

To generate the message I used some function in the jsfUtil.java:

```
public class JsfUtil {

public static SelectItem[] getSelectItems(List<?> entities, boolean selectOne){
    int size = selectOne ? entities.size() + 1 : entities.size();
    SelectItem[] items = new SelectItem[size];
    int i = 0;
    if (selectOne){
        items[0] = new SelectItem("", "---");
        i++;
    }
    for (Object x : entities){
        items[i++] = new SelectItem(x, x.toString());
    }
    return items;
}

public static void addErrorMessage(Exception ex, String defaultMsg) {
    String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
    if (msg != null && msg.length() > 0) {
        addErrorMessage(msg);
    } else {
        addErrorMessage(defaultMsg);
    }
}

    public static void addErrorMessages(List<String> messages) {
    for (String message : messages) {
        addErrorMessage(message);
    }
}

public static void addErrorMessage(String msg) {
    FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, msg);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);
}

    public static void addSuccessMessage(String msg) {
    FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, msg);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("successInfo", facesMsg);
}

public static String getRequestParameter(String key) {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(key);
}

public static Object getObjectFromRequestParameter(String requestParameterName, Converter converter, UIComponent component) {
    String theId = JsfUtil.getRequestParameter(requestParameterName);
    return converter.getAsObject(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), component, theId);
}
}
```

Example of function who generates an message:

```
public String doUpdate() {
    try {
        modelFacade.edit(current);
        items = new ListDataModel(modelFacade.find(new ModelSearch()));
        current = (Model) getItems().getRowData();        

        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Mise à jour Executée");
        return "Model.xhtml";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

At this moment all message are displayed into the div but i would like to change how the div display the message in function of the message type (ex: green ok; yellow warning; red error).

How can I link a css style to my div in function of the message generated by this function?

Comment: This question is strange. The answer would be "use `infoClass`, `warnClass`, `errorClass`, `fatalClass`". But you're already using it. Although I see nowhere CSS, so I gather that your actual question is that you have no idea how to write CSS for that?

Comment: I forgot to include the css but the css only color the div when a message is generated at the moment. I'm looking to be able to chose the color of the div depending the type of error

Answer (score 1):

Create a css file and include this classes:

```
.info{
  background-color: green;
}

.warn{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.err{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Then in your main xhtml in the  section you include the css file like this:

```
 <link href="#/[pathToMyCssFile]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Edit**

You need to add an `id` to your `h:messages` (Only one is necessary the css class will be applied automatically depending on the Severity)

```
<h:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true" errorClass="err" warnClass="warn" infoClass="info"></h:messages>
```

You'll have to add this id to the methods where you add the message
for example:

```
public static void addErrorMessage(String msg) {
    FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, msg);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messages", facesMsg);
}



public static void addSuccessMessage(String msg) {
    FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, msg);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messages", facesMsg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how I can assign dynamically the class used by the div?
As I said, I would like to apply the class .info .warn .err depending of the message generated

Comment: @Ersch which div mean do you the h:messages?

Comment: I want to use a single div but be able to change the background color depending the message type. 
This is the code into the div at the moment:
`<h:messages globalOnly="true" errorClass="err" warnClass="warn" infoClass="info"></h:messages>
    <h:messages globalOnly="false" errorClass="err" warnClass="warn" infoClass="info"></h:messages>`

Comment: I'm not sure of the result, I want to change the background color of the div. So the function addSuccessMessage should define the css style of the div and not the <h:messages ?